# Populate big array list to drop down using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue. I have a collection of object with size around 22K records. I need to bind this to an select element. Binding is working fine for small collection but such a big collection is freezing UI until its bind completely.

Please suggest the best I can do here....

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Comment: code is simple as angular binding

Comment: you need to go for angular ui `typeahead` or look for plugin like `ui-select` with lazyloading

Comment: curious - what would you do with 22k records in a select box?

Answer (score 4):

First thing that pops to mind is using `one-way data binding`. That is accomplished by appending `::` in front of your HTML variables like so

```
{{::someVar}}
```

This way, angular will not include `someVar` in its `watchers`.

If that is still not enough for you then you might consider writing a special type of `select` for your own purposes which can use something like [ClusterizeJS](http://nexts.github.io/Clusterize.js/) behind it.

`ClusterizeJS` allows only rendering a few elements on the screen and re-rendering on scroll such that the user will never know that not all the elements already exist in the `select`. Couple this with a `search bar` and you've got yourself a very fast `select`.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not wise to populate a `<select>` element with such a huge number of records. That applies no matter which framework you are using (although it would be especially bad with Angular and two way data binding).

Where you want the user to be able to select from a large number of options, I would recommend using an 'autocomplete' style of interface, where the user types a few characters and the client fetches options that match what they have typed so far.

For example, you could use [Angular-UI select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)